# Get-ADUser not accurately returning EmployeeID attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have some users who we've confirmed have the employeeID attribute set by viewing their attributes in Attribute Editor of Active Directory Users and Computers. However, for those same users, when we attempt to run a `Get-ADUser "UsernameHereWithoutQuotes" -properties *`, it displays the EmployeeID attribute as being blank.

We run a hybrid Azure environment and this is causing issues with some of our powershell scripting and dynamic groups not matching up. Some groups are managed by Powershell scripts which, since the employeeID attribute is appearing blank via powershell, doesn't include the user when we have a `filter {employeeID -eq "*"}` to check for users with that attribute populated.

Has anyone had any similar issues like this or can share any advice? We set the attributes for these users months ago so it's not that we're running it before replication occurs, and we repeated these same tests (checking ADUC Attribute Editor and running a `get-aduser`) on multiple DC's and all are returning the same issue.

Comment: just to be sure of things ... are you _certain_ that you are not mixing `EmployeeID` & `EmployeeNumber`?

Comment: Yep, 100% certain. Both fields reported as blank via Powershell (`-properties *` to verify), only EmployeeNumber is blank in Attribute Editor.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! [*grin*]  i see that `Oggew` found your problem - permissions. **you may want to check to see WHY that non-standard permission is set. odd settings that are not documented can indicate someone/something doing things that you may want to put a stop to ...** [*frown*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running Powershell as administrator (elevated) and it should work.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me. For some reason (guessing different security levels?) Powershell will pull some attributes while running it as a non-admin but not all attributes. And note that this was different per-user as well, some users accurately returned the `employeeID` while others didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my environment, so it's not a general issue.

What do you get from running the following?

```
$PDCEmulator = ([DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers | Where-Object { $_.Roles -contains 'PdcRole' }).Name

Get-ADUser username -properties EmployeeID -Server $PDCEmulator
```

Comment: Issue ended up being running powershell in non-admin mode returned the `employeeID` for some users but not all. Running the command in an admin powershell window returned it for all users.